# AWS EKS - Dead container cleanup

Tags: kubernetes, garbage-collection, containers, amazon-eks

I am using Terraform to create infrastructure on AWS environment. Out of many services, we are also creating AWS EKS using terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws module. The EKS is primarily used for spinning dynamic containers to handle asynchronous job execution. Once a given task is completed the container releases resources and terminates.

What I have noticed is that, the dead containers lying on the EKS cluster forever. This is causing too many dead containers just sitting on EKS and consuming storage. I came across few blogs which mention that Kubernetes has garbage collection process, but none describes how it can be specified using Terraform or explicitly for AWS EKS.

Hence I am looking for a solution, which will help to specify garbage collection policy for dead containers on AWS EKS. If not achievable via Terraform, I am ok with using kubectl with AWS EKS.

Comment: * check k8s docs about [garbage_collection](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/garbage-collection/) , and how to use finalizers ( forground method ) and [cascading orphans](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/use-cascading-deletion/#set-orphan-deletion-policy)

* Most probably, EKS not exposing such internals so you should control that  over kubectl @CuriousMind

Comment: @TamerElfeky Thanks for your response and the references.  I have seen the k8 docs. Let me check it again :)

Answer (score 0):

These two kubelet flags will cause the node to clean up docker images when the filesystem reaches those percentages. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/garbage-collection/#container-image-lifecycle

```
--image-gc-high-threshold="85"
--image-gc-low-threshold="80"
```

But you also probably want to set `--maximum-dead-containers 1` so that running multiple (same) images doesn't leave dead containers around.

In EKS you can add these flags to the UserData section of your EC2 instance/Autoscaling group.

```
#!/bin/bash 
set -o xtrace 
/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh --apiserver-endpoint ..... --kubelet-extra-args '<here>'
```

Comment: Hey @Ryan Thanks for your reply. I have seen this documentation, but how it can be applied on AWS EKS?

Comment: @CuriousMind you can apply it in your EKS autoscaling group userdata. See my edited post.

Comment: I truly appreciate for taking out time. I spin up EKS using https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/ module and we are leveraging AWS managed (not self-managed) instances. The autoscaling is achieved using Cluster Autoscaler and except instance type, we do not provide any information in TF scripts.